# СокОл и сокол - есть ли связь?

Tags: этимология, омонимы, однокоренные-слова

Как известно, в выражении "гол, как сокол" речь идет не о птице, а о заточенном коле. Но это слово от названия птицы отличается только ударением. Интересно было бы узнать, случайно это или нет?
Со словом "сокОл" более понятно, тут явно прослеживается "кол" (правда, не знаю, что означает часть "со-"). А вот как быть с птицей? Какое происхождение ее название и имеет ли оно какую-то связь со словом "сокОл"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сокол - название птицы, и до определенного времени оно произносилось с ударением на втором слоге - сокОл (Словарь 1847 - **сокОлъ**). Это до сих пор слышится в уменьшительном *сокОлик*.
В переносном значении :

> || Сокол, бойное орудие разного рода, большой железный лом, или баран, таран, **стенобитное орудие, подвешенное на цепях**; ручная баба, трамбовка или пест.
> (Словарь Даля)

*СокОл* летал на цепях и клевал стены железным клювом. Перенос значения довольно меткий.